# how to submit remote file from curl request as form data

Tags: php, forms, curl, file-upload

My PHP app is set up so that users can save/upload files via a form. I'm trying to write a shell script (to be run by a cron job) which re-uses the same model methods, but for a file which is NOT submitted via a form. I'm currently using curl to fetch the file, but I'm open to other solutions.

Here is how I currently fetch the file:

```
$ch = curl_init($image_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$photo_data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This appears to return base64 encoded data...

```
Hâ6#Ý^¦Ó­¾ÊiAM¸¤¨q±´°jîÍrÓÄ¥!dqh/J°ØÉ(þ}ZKóÜ§óµßÅÑ  .JÍWE-uXØ¤u!¢
±IãJT æµ¯utÞfåã6MGâYØUL:ÑÆZS÷'5Óç;ªåÓÒâbmlLKsô«ÄT
±üåûü_Ä¦SSM"ºlDAº¦Ë]Xcç[)X©¬oÞÃîIöÁB]aR+%+å@_·]³
...
```

Here is the format of the post data which my app is expecting:

```
[Photo] => Array
    (
        [file] => Array
            (
                [name] => desert2.jpg
                [type] => image/jpeg
                [tmp_name] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/php65uUCk
                [error] => 0
                [size] => 96573
            )

    )
```

So my question is how can I make the `curl`ed file data accessible to the script which normally handles data from the above post request?

Comment: PHP has a base64_decode function build in. You would have to parse that into the format needed. I'm on my phone right now so I can't provide documentation but a quick google search should help.

Comment: Thanks @JoeKasavage . I know of the `base64_decode` function but I'm still not sure what to do after that. How do I get the file/data into the tmp location or wherever POSTed files normally end up?

Comment: The file being an image you can do it a couple ways. You can convert the base64 to a file or what I like to do is add the string to a database and prepend the image/jpeg to it and if you put that string in an image source it will show or you can do the same with a link just to the image.

Comment: @JoeKasavage I think I half-understand. I haven't tried yet, but I think I understand how to decode the data and save it as a file. The part I'm still fuzzy on is how to make the file accessible to it the method. Do I manually create a tmp_name and save it to the tmp location? I'm used to the server settings basically handling that stuff (after a form submission) so I'm not sure how to recreate it. If you have a chance, could you submit an answer with some example code, or even just pseudo code?

Comment: I can come do a full write up on it in a little bit. Hopefully an hour or so, working on some client work at the moment. I find the best way to be an ajax call allowing blob data type to pass the information back and forth in base64.

Comment: Great! It may be important to point out that this script will be running server side, triggered by a cron job.

Comment: Could you post an example of the data you receive back from the cURL? I will have to add an answer today. Had some unfortunate server problems that had to be fixed today.

Comment: @JoeKasavage I updated the question with an example of the returned data. It's just base64 gibberish.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I should be able to have it done soon.

Comment: Is this a full response? When I try to convert it I am getting just a blank variable.

Comment: Oh. No! Sorry the full response is several screens long of characters...

Comment: Also I think I was wrong about the data being base64 encoded. When I use `base64_decode` it returns false and instead if I just pass the raw string to `file_put_contents` it just works (without decoding).

Comment: I was just going to bring up how it did not look like base64, ha. Are you having any other problems? If so feel free to reach out and I can assist. This is one of those times I wish there was a private message system, lol.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69128/discussion-between-sdp-and-joe-kasavage).

Comment: I'm still not sure what to do with the data. I can save the file to the server... but my script STILL expects file data to be coming from a form (via the $_POST array?) and I don't know how to recreate that manually.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

```
<?php

// cURL
$ch = curl_init($image_url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$photo_data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 

// Create Image Array
$imageData = array(
                "name"=>"IMAGE NAME",
                "type"=>"image/jpeg",
                "tmp_name"=>"TEMP NAME",
                "error"=>0,
                "size"=>str_len($photo_data),
                "photo"=>$imageData // Add this line as there is nothing in the data structure given that will pass the image data
             );

// URL
$url = parse_url("http://www.wherethisisgoing.com/page.php");

$host = $url["host"];
$path = $url["path"];

$httpData = http_build_query($imageData); // Converts array to URL Parameters

$socket = fopensock($host, 80, $errno, $error, 30); // 80 is the port and 30 is the timeout length

if($socket) {
    fputs($socket, "POST " . $path . " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    fputs($socket, "Host: " . $host . "\r\n");
    fputs($socket, "Referrer: PUT SENDING URL HERE\r\n");
    fputs($socket, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
    fputs($socket, "Content-length " . strlen($imageData) . "\r\n");
    fputs($socket, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
    fputs($socket, $imageData);

    while(feof($socket)) {
        // Get Results
        $result .= fgets($socket, 128); // 128 should be enough to receive the response from the script
    }
} else {
    return array(
                    "status"=>"error",
                    "error"=>$error . " (" . $errno . ")" 
                );
}

//Do some type of checking to verify the image was uploaded

fclose($socket);
```